# Why does "attr -l ." tell me about an "selinux" attribute that "attr -g selinux ." refuses to read?

Tags: selinux, xattr

I'm setting up a Fedora (Core) 24 system from scratch, and ran into this oddness:

```
> sudo attr -l .
Attribute "selinux" has a 41 byte value for .

> sudo attr -g selinux .
attr_get: No data available
Could not get "selinux" for .
```

(similar for files other than ".", the current directory, I just used that as an example).

Is this just part of selinux's own security that the tag it assigns a file is unreadable? Or is there something else going on here?

As requested, I ran some additional commands, this time on ".bashrc":

```
# attr -l .bashrc 
Attribute "selinux" has a 37 byte value for .bashrc

# ls -Z .bashrc 
unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 .bashrc

# echo "unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0"|wc -c
37
```

So I guess "unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0" is the value, it's just odd "attr -g selinux" doesn't give it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out it is partially a namespace issue.
the selinux is in the security namespace.
So: sudo attr -S -g selinux .
should get you the value.
It seems that the attr -l path is listing the security as well as the user namespace attributes, but not letting on about the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an *XFS* filesystem?  It isn't the default on Fedora; did you explicitly arrange that during the installation?

If not, that is probably the reason.  The command *attr* is for *XFS* filesystems.  Check the manual page for details.

What exactly is it you want to do?  If you want to see the SELinux context for a file, use `ls -Z`.  If you want to assign your own *user* attributes, use the commands `getfattr` and `setfattr`.

Comment: I did encrypt the filesystem but didn't otherwise make any changes: I even accepted the default partitioning. I think ext4 (and maybe even ext3 and ext2) support extended file system attributes, and I can use extended attributes on my old Fedora Core 11 default installation.

Comment: Yes, several file systems support extended attributes.  But the `attr` command is only designed for the `XFS` variant.

Comment: `attr` seems to work on Fedora 24 default system, and comes "pre-installed". See also my edits to my original question.

Comment: It works somewhat, in that it finds an attribute and knows its length.  But it can not read it, so it isn't working correctly.  The attribute name is actually namespaced, it is `security.selinux`.  That too seems to get out wrong when using `attr` on a non-XFS filesystem.  Read `man 1 attr` and `man 5 attr` for more information.

Comment: OK, but `getfattr -d .` yields nothing at all. I suspect there's some confusion between `attr` vs `getfattr` and `setfattr`, but all three are included by default in a Fedora 24 installation.

Comment: XFS is available in Fedora, you **can** use it if you want.  So it isn't surprising `attr` is included in the distribution.  As far as I know, the `*fattr` commands can only access the _user_ domain attributes, but I'm not sure about that part.